# Decline meetings in Outlook from a specific sender

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, meeting-request

I know that this may have been posted before but none of the answers are working out for me. I would like to decline all meetings originating from a specific sender. The options which I have tried are:

1. Outlook Rules

`Apply this rule after the message arrives 
 from XXX
  and which is a meeting invitation or update
 delete it`

The trouble with this rule is that it really is not working. This is the top most rule in my rule list and the `FROM` sender is exact but it does not match.

2. I have explored some options about using VBA scripts but the trouble with that is that rule will get applied only when Outlook on my PC is running. I'd like to have the rules stored on the server so they are processed centrally.

Please let me know what options are available or if I'm doing something wrong.

Thank you

Comment: Hey, Abhishek Sha - see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1210535/is-there-any-way-to-auto-decline-meeting-invites-based-on-rules-like-for-mail/1495190#comment2529700_1495190). This solved the problem for me partially. It raised [a new question](https://superuser.com/questions/1660218/do-not-show-reminders-for-appointments-of-a-specific-category-in-outlook), though.

Answer (score 1):

When you say the rule is not working, does the initial message stay in your Inbox, or is the message deleted but you still see a meeting on your calendar?

Comment: The invite isn't deleted.