# Is there any way to auto-decline meeting invites based on rules like for mail?

Tags: mac, microsoft-outlook

So we have a huge team and lately I'm constantly getting "Joe Schmuckatelli Dentist Appointment" and stuff like that and I really don't need to know this info....they are either on slack/Lync or they are not.  I silently decline that crap because I have enough legit meetings on my calendar.

Is there any way to set up a rule in Outlook for Mac that allows me to silently decline any meetings that match the rules of say, To: #teamname and contain “WFH”, “OOO”, “PTO” etc?

Answer (score 9):

It's complicated but to actually decline the meeting you can do the following:

- https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sharepoint_republic/2011/12/09/outlook-rule-to-auto-accept-or-auto-decline-meeting-invites/

**A hack is to auto-hide meeting invites from the calendar** view by:

- Create an Outlook Category called "Invisible"
- Create a mail rule to auto-tag meeting invites with the "Invisible" category
- Change the calendar view to not display items in the "Invisible" category
- Outlook Calendar View → View (tab) → View Settings (button) → Filter (button) → Advanced (tab) → Field "Categories" : "doesn't contain" : "Invisible"

Comment: This is an elegant solution that allows you to not have to _delete_ the invitations to not have them show in your Calendar. Great answer.

Comment: Hey,  DH4 - please take a look at [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1660218/do-not-show-reminders-for-appointments-of-a-specific-category-in-outlook), if you don't mind. Hope you can help me there, too!

Comment: That doesn't allow me to indicate to the sender that I won't be able to attend the said meeting. (Also, would still show me as unavailable during that time to others trying to invite me to meetings that are actually important)

Comment: Note that if you use teams, the hidden meetings will still pollute your chat history. Better to use the auto decline script.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is

(while in mail view, not Calendar view)
In the “Organize” ribbon, select “Rules”->“Create Rule”
“From” “is” #greenhouse
“Subject”  Contains ‘PTO’ or ‘WFH’
“Kind” Is ‘meeting request’
“Delete”

Comment: delete is not the same as decline

Comment: Good point but isn't the effect the same (remove from my calendar)?  I don't care if the organizer knows.

Comment: Not same effect actually: just deleting from my calendar doesn't send a response to the organizer, so they'll just keep resending it until you do respond....