# Do not show reminders for appointments of a specific category in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook

In trying to automate my calendar-handling in Outlook via rules I've found that the best approach available is the one described here: [Is there any way to auto-decline meeting invites based on rules like for mail?](https://superuser.com/questions/1210535/is-there-any-way-to-auto-decline-meeting-invites-based-on-rules-like-for-mail/1495190#comment2529700_1495190). As a result of [the solution](https://superuser.com/a/1495190/345077) I get to 'hide' the appointments from my calendar.

However, I still get the reminder notification popups. I see options to disable all notifications, but no custom options.

Is there a way to disable notifications for scheduled appointments of a particular category?

Answer (score 3):

As I know, there seems to be no direct way to remove all special meeting notifications at one time. Through my research, as a workaround, it’s suggested that you could remove the notifications one by one in the list view of the calendar. For specific steps, please refer to:

1.In Calendar>click View>Change view>List;

2.Click the clock icon circled in red in the figure below, and all the email with notification will be displayed together;
[image]

3.Uncheck the clock icon in front of the messages you want to remove one by one.

Hope the above help!

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.

Comment: Christy, it's a useful tip for handling manually but I'm mostly concerned with automating this. So I'm leaving the question unanswered